# Python Value not Adding

Tags: python

here is a snippet of code from a bigger project I am working on.

```
import time
value = 0
xyz = 1
while xyz == 1:
    print(value + 1)
    time.sleep(1)
```

This just prints 1 infinitely instead of going 1,2,3,4 etc.

Comment: why should it increment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never change `value`. If you want to increment it every iteration, add `value += 1` or `value = value + 1` to the loop.

```
while xyz == 1:
    value += 1
    print(value)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: @MagikCow:  Then what language are you using?  Not Python.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski It is python

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is printing `1` repeatedly. You are just doing a `print(value + 1)`

If you are expecting `value` to change, you need to reassign it, not just print it.

```
while xyz == 1:
    value = value + 1
    print(value)
    time.sleep(1)
```

This seems to be inline with what you are expecting.

---

Another note, you can adjust `while xyz == 1:` to `while True:` if you are planning an infinite loop and not going to modify `xyz`